# An electromagnetic induction problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

The question goes like this :

> A thin non conducting horizontal disc of mass $m$ having total charge $q$ distributed uniformly over its surface, can rotate freely about its own axis. Initially when the disk is stationary a magnetic field $B$ directed perpendicular to the plane is switched on at $t=0$. Find the angular velocity $\omega$ acquired by disc as a function of time, if $B=kt$, where $k$ is an arbitrary non-zero constant and $t$ is time

The given diagram :

[image: Disc in time varying magnetic field]

What I did was to find out the induced emf in the loop due to the changing magnetic flux, using Faraday's laws. These are my results:

The emf:$$ \epsilon=k\pi R^2$$

The magnetic moment of the disc when it rotates with angular velocity $\omega$ :
$$\mu=\frac{q\omega R^2}{2}$$

But now I am stuck. What should be my next step? Any hints??

Comment: You need to formulate equation of motion for the disk -the equation "torque = rate of change of angular momentum". Then you need to find torque for given state of the system ($B, \omega$). Then solve the equation for $\omega(t)$.

Comment: If the problem is posed as stated, I think there are a couple of issues with the attempted solution. 1) it is stated to be a (continuous) disk, not a loop, and 2) the disk is stated to be **nonconducting**, so an approach based on induced emf is not appropriate.

Comment: all right, granted that induced emf wouldn't help but then if I do it based on magnetic moment, then we can see that torque would be $0$ as magnetic moment and magnetic field are in same direction.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can calculate the electric field it generates using the Maxwell equations and it should be a constant field. Then with the field you can calculate the torque exerted on the disc and thus you can get the $\omega(t)$.